# how to pass a request parameter in retrofit post request

Tags: java, android, spring, post, retrofit

I have a post request that will send details to the server. The condition is that each user was assigned a unique value to and this value must be passed when the user want to place the request. I have a model class that is passed through the `@Body` annotation but I don't know how to pass this user's unique key along with this model class.

The key was passed in the backend as a request parameter. Please note that this token is not as an `Authorization header`, it's just a unique token that was assigned to each user for authentication purpose

Here is how the backend looks like It was developed with `Spring boot`

```
@PostMapping("appointment/book")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> bookAppointment(@RequestBody AppointmentBookingDto appointmentBookingDto, @RequestParam("token") String token) throws DataNotFoundException, ParseException, DataAlreadyExistException {
  return appointmentBookingService.bookAppointment(appointmentBookingDto, token);
}
```

This is how I tried to pass it in my interface class in android studio

```
@POST("appointment/book")
Call<ApiResponse> bookAppointment(@Body AppointmentBookingDto appointmentBookingDto, @Path("token") String token);
```

Here is the activity that I called the bookAppointment method.

```
 private void bookAppointment() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        date = btnDate.getText().toString();
        time = btnTime.getText().toString();

        AppointmentBookingDto appointmentBookingDto = new AppointmentBookingDto(time, date, purpose.getText().toString());

        Call<ApiResponse> call = BaseUrlClient
                .getInstance().getApi().bookAppointment(
                        appointmentBookingDto, token.getText().toString()
                );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 201) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("Main",response.body().getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(BookAppointmentActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    try {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("Main", "Response code is " + response.code());
                        Log.d("Main", "Error message is " + response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Main", "Failure message is " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(BookAppointmentActivity.this, "Error " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are calling `bookAppointment()` I wanted to see where are you passing token.

Comment: I have edited the code, please check it out because I have added the path that the method is called in the activity @VishalBeep

Comment: [updated] check answer now!

Comment: Thanks so much @VishalBeep, It's now working perfectly, I only changed the Path to Query in my Android without changing anything in the backend and it's executed correctly

Comment: make sure to upvote  if you think it helps future devs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for how to pass `parameter` in retrofit but in your backend you are accepting `query` for example -

You are asking for -

```
https://yourdoman.com/appointment/book/12345
```

But your spring backend accepting something like this -

```
https://yourdoman.com/appointment/book?token=12345
```

> so you can solve this issue by either changing in backend or frontend (Android)

I'm showing you both

**Solve by changing only frontend which is android -**

You can can change `@Path` to `@Query` like this :

```
@POST("appointment/book")
Call<ApiResponse> bookAppointment(@Body AppointmentBookingDto 
appointmentBookingDto, @Query("token") String token);
```

or

**Solve by changing only backend (Spring)**

> Note : I didn't used spring yet but I have noticed this from doc.

Instead of using `@RequestParam` use `@PathVariable` something like this :

```
 @PostMapping("appointment/book/{token}")
 public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> bookAppointment(@RequestBody AppointmentBookingDto appointmentBookingDto,
 @PathVariable String token) throws DataNotFoundException, ParseException, DataAlreadyExistException {
   return appointmentBookingService.bookAppointment(appointmentBookingDto,token);
}
```

and make sure you only apply one solution don't change from both

let me know if it helps :)